# Is losing faith the same with learned helplessness?

Tags: terminology, belief, trust, learned-helplessness

According to Merriam-Webster, the definition of [Lose Faith In](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lose%20faith%20in) is:

> to no longer believe that (someone or something) can be trusted

For example: lost faith in government, in love, in humanity, in oneself, in life, etc.

Is this the same with [Learned Helplessness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learned_helplessness)? Or at least a type of it? Because learned helplessness can be classically conditioned, which "lose faith in" doesn't seem to imply. However, it seems that learned helplessness can also be occurred solely in one's belief.

If I don't believe that I can have any chance to become the president of the USA, am I having learned helplessness? If I think there is a small possibility, but it's just too small that it isn't worth my effort to try, so it's just simpler to say that I don't have any chance, am I having learned helplessness?

<sub>Related:

• [Does the “learned” in “learned helplessness” refer specifically to behaviorism's conditioning?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/26617/12937)

• [How does one escape learned helplessness?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/19208/12937)

• [What is the difference between conditioning and learning?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/25863/12937)</sub>

Comment: Why do you think they'd be the same or one is a subset of the other?

Comment: Losing faith implies that the person has that faith before. The dog in Seligman's experiment once had "faith" that it could escape